# graphics card not detected

Tags: graphics

I am using a hp laptop with radeon graphics. The output of 
lspci | grep VGA    command is 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
I think the graphics card is not recognised properly. When I start my computer this screen appears always. However ubuntu is booted then.

https://github.com/nikcodes/nikcodes.github.io/blob/master/IMG_20180621_113825_HHT.jpg
This happened only after I updated my kernel to 4.15. The reason I think this is a problem is that two time before my system couldn't start and it gave 'The system is running in low graphics mode'. Pls refer this link to see a screenshot
https://github.com/nikcodes/nikcodes.github.io/blob/master/IMG_20180615_130059.jpg.
Both times I had to uninstall and gave it a fresh install and all my data got erased. I also tried booting in the failsafeX mode but nothing showed except than 'system running in low graphics mode'. Even now when ubuntu is atleast booting up it gives the same low graphics mode error when I tried failsafeX mode. So I think the radeon graphics is not configured correctly. Pls help me with that